# How can you use Linq result with RDLC report?

Tags: c#, linq, rdlc

I have the following method:

```
private void GetTransactions(string rptType, string acadYrs)
    {
        rptData = new Transactions();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = rpt.GetTenantContractListByYear(acadYrs);
        rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetTenantContract", ds.Tables[0]);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

        //Load report
        LoadReport(rptType);

        //Assign report
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

        //set report parameters
        this.SetReportParameters(acadYrs);

        //refresh report
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
```

i have a method that return a LINQ result, so how can i fill the dataset with 
LINQ query and replace

```
ds = rpt.GetTenantContractListByYear(acadYrs);
```

with

```
ds = rpt.GetDataFromLINQ(acadYrs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the overloads for `ReportDataSource` is:

```
public ReportDataSource(string name, IEnumerable dataSourceValue)
```

Assuming the result of your LINQ statement is a list (it usually is), just assign it directly:

```
rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSetTenantContract", rpt.GetDataFromLINQ(acadYrs));
```

Comment: ,i tried that but it returns a report only the header with no data

Comment: Yes there are the same name

Comment: i checked again the fields as you said it

Answer (score 1):

Add a new `dataset` to your project. Add a `datatableadapter` for this `dataset` and set the query for this adapter the query of your LINQ.

if Dasaset1 is your `dataset` name then:

```
private void GetTransactions(string rptType, string acadYrs)
    {

        //set report parameters
        this.SetReportParameters(acadYrs);

        //refresh report
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
       this.DataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.DataSet1.DataTable1);
    }
```